# How/where to store frequently updated values securely?

Tags: c#, vb6

I'm working on an application now that controls a hardware device.  For various reasons (self-service, warranty, general information to the operator, etc.), I need to store usage data, and especially running time of the hardware.  This needs to be updated somewhat frequently (at least every minute).

As such, I need the usage data to:

1. be available for the application no matter which user launches it.
2. remain unaltered no matter if the application it reinstalled.
3. be somewhat difficult (if not impossible) for the user to change.
4. not need admin rights to be written and read by the application.

Currently the application is written in Visual Basic 6.0.  But it will be rewritten in C# soon, and it would be interesting to use the same method there as well.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: A lightweight *Database* such as SQLite / SQL Server Compact

Comment: A good idea for a new c# platform.  But our aim is "as little work as possible" for the present vb6 platform.  I'm a little hesitant about adding a completely new major component, such as an SQL database.

Comment: Most solutions are going to be very different in VB6 vs modern NET solutions.

Comment: Seems like you are limited to flat files in VB6 then.

Comment: SQL, the registry (ewww), flat text files (also pretty ewww), flat json files, flat xml files.

Comment: @AlexK. Where would you store such a file, to adhere to points 1, 2 and 4?

Comment: @PaulSwetz I've looked at the registry.  But the problem is writing access.  HKLM needs admin rights, and groups not needing admin rights aren't available across different computer users, as far as I can see...  Correct me if I'm wrong.. :-)

Comment: `%SystemDrive%\ProgramData\YourComp\YourApp` as for point 2 you would build that logic into your installer or generate a unique name on first run.

Comment: Agree with Alex though if you're worried about your users looking for and potentially altering the file I'd make the folders you use more vague so it's not obviously attached to your app/company. Might even try to stick it under Microsoft! #3 would be by far my biggest concern at least. The other 3 criteria are easily dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a file of some format that supports efficient updating.  In many cases INI format is good enough, and even plain text might be as long as you manage "random" updating properly.  The file format doesn't matter and is up to you.  Even a Jet 4.0 MDB could make sense if you have a lot of data but there is no reason to deploy some ad hoc 3rd party embedded DBMS engine for this.  Jet 4.0 and ADO both ship in Windows so there is nothing to deploy, in contrast to something like SQLite.

The trick is to put this where it is available to all users for updating.

The best answer is for your installer running elevated to create an application-unique folder under the `ProgramData` special folder and set security on this to Full Control or something somewhat less for all logged-on users (the `Everyone` group works for this these days since it excludes `Guest`).

You can use Shell Flat API calls or Shell Automation objects to look up `ProgramData` (`ssfCOMMONAPPDATA` a.k.a. `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA` or even the newer `FOLDERID_ProgramData` with newer Shell calls).

Avoid the use of Environment Variables and hard coded name strings for this, that is unreliable.  Environment Variables can be altered and name strings can be localized or change from version to version of Windows.

If your installer is not smart enough to handle this you can also do it as part of your program's *first run actions* and it doesn't even require elevation.  The creating user has *owner access* on the created subfolder, and so has permission to broaden access to all users.

Normally the unique part of the created folder's path uses Company Name and Product Name.  Typically your code takes these from values you can fetch via the VB6 `App` object.

See [[VB6] ProgramData for common files](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?824911-VB6-ProgramData-for-common-files) for a VB6 code sample.